# jQuery - how can I set a proxy?

Tags: jquery, proxy

Is this possible? Looking for a way to set a proxy setting view web page. Can I embed it or run some JavaScript, etc...

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: I'm asking if jQuery has this type of functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this php